# Characteristic function say something about the expectation and variance

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, characteristic-functions

Show that if $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} (\varphi(t) -1) / t^2 = c > -\infty$ then $EX = 0$ and $E|X|^2 = -2c < \infty$. In particular, if $\varphi(t) = 1 + o(t^2)$, then $\varphi(t) \equiv 1$. Where $\varphi(t)$ is the characteristic function of $X$.

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use theorem 3.3.9 followed by 3.3.8 in Durrett's text.

(I assume you are working from this text, as your last two questions are directly from it)

Comment: @user112564 It's not too bad. I assumed you were in the class, but didn't mention it because user112564 is too difficult a pseudonym to decipher